# PDO DB connection issues

Tags: php, activerecord, pdo

I have changed the code a bit, but nothing changed. I'm obviously not able to use PDO correctly.

So, the db connection is here:

```
class Database {
private static $instance = null;
private function __construct(){}
     public static function getInstance() {
     if(is_null(self::$instance)){
     self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host = localhost, dbname = elektro", "root", "");

     }
     return self::$instance; 
      }

}
```

This class deals with the DB:

```
abstract class ActiveRecord {   
private static $conn;
public static function getAll(){
     $conn = Database::getInstance();
     $table = static::$table;
     $class = get_called_class();
     $q = self::$conn->query("select * from {$table}");
     $res = $q->fetchAll();
     return $res;

      }

     }
```

And this one is supposed to fetch all rows from one table:

```
class Autor extends ActiveRecord {
public static $table = "autor";
}
$conn = Database::getInstance();
$allAutors = Autor::getAll();
print_r($allAutors);
```

This results in Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null

Comment: Where is the variable `static::$table` coming from? Could you dump out your query `"select * from" . static::$table` as a string and try to run it manually? It seems like your query does not go through correctly so you might have SQL errors.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I have another class that is supposed to handle one table in the database called "author". This is where I declared the $table variable and set it to table name. 

    class Author extends ActiveRecord {

    public static $table = "author";
    }

Comment: Your `$q` variable seems to return a `boolean` (probably false) showing that something is wrong. I would still dump out the query and try to run it. Also you could add a check `if(!$q) var_dump($conn->errorInfo());` to see the actual errors: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: LOL :) The issue was no space after "select * from" and the concatenated variable. However, now when I try to run the class that extends ActiveRecord, I get "Warning: PDOStatement::fetch() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in...", pointing to the place where i try to get called class. This is apparently not how you do that...

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. `fetch` expects these arguments: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php What exactly do you want to do with the class name in your database?

Comment: I need the class name so the ActiveRecord class can be completely abstract. I plan to extend it to other classes that handle different tables in a database - I'd like to specify which class used the getAll method. I modeled it after a mysqli example, but I still can't figure out how to "turn" this into PDO.

    abstract class ActiveRecord {
 public static function getAll(){ 
  $q = mysqli_query(Database::getInstance(),
  "select * from ".static::$table . ");
  $res = array();
  while($rw=mysqli_fetch_object($q,get_called_class())) 
   $res[] = $rw; 
  return $res;}